# Polling: Page getting refreshed any filter/sorting order specified is also getting reset. How can i prevent this from happening?

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, ag-grid, polling

I am using `agGrid` to display API data on my page. I have implemented polling to fetch data periodically after every 30secs. But after every 30secs with the page getting refreshed any filter/sorting order specified is also getting reset. How can I prevent this from happening? I want to keep filter/sorting intact when auto refresh happens.

```typescript
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.update(); //auto refresh method
    this.defaultColumnDefs = defaultColumnDefs;
    this.translator = this.i18Service.getTranslator();
    this.translator.translateObject.subscribe((item: any) => {
      this.locales = item;
    });
    this.columnDefs = deviceColumnDefs();
    this.getPatientVisitList();
    this.getPatientDeviceList();
    this.isRowSelected = false;

  }

  
   //update method-- polling logic 

  update(){
    this.timeInterval = interval(10000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.deviceService.getDeviceList())
      )
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.deviceService.flag$),
        repeatWhen(() => this.deviceService.flag$)
      )
      .subscribe((success: any) => {
        this.rowData = success;
        console.log("hello")
      }, retry(2));
    

  //This is the method I am calling in service.

  getDeviceList() {
    const endPointUrl = `${getServerUrl()}/getDeviceResource`;
    return this.http.get(endPointUrl);
    
  }
```

Comment: is your entire page refreshing? and where are you setting/updating the grid data?

Comment: yes i am polling the api after every 30sec. In the same component

Comment: your page shouldn't need to refresh, your can update the data in your grid without refreshing and hence your filters and sorting staying intact, [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-8fjg8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Could u please elaborate what changes do i need to make in current code to keep sorting and filters intact?

Comment: my current code is also handling the case of stopping the timer when i open any popup

Comment: please reproduce your issue in either Stackblitz or Plunker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228510/discussion-between-shilpi-dhiman-and-viqmontana).

Comment: was this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple if you use grid api to set row data.

In template :

```
<ag-grid-angular [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

in component :

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
    rowData: this.rowData,
};
```

in your `update()` method :

```
    subscribe((success: any) => {
        const model = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel(); // get the current filter state
        this.rowData = success; // new row data
        this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.rowData); // set row data using grid api
        this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(model); // set the filter
  }
```

make sure not to bind rowData in template, don't do this :

```
<ag-grid-angular [rowData]="rowData"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ag-Grid integrated with AdapTable?

If so then you can use their api to get the current search and filter state before refresh and then immediately apply it after refresh.  Or, simpler, you can set the 'reapplyFiltersOnGridSetData' in Adaptable Options.

Answer (score 0):

I added this property in my column definition and it started working fine.

```
filterParams: {
newRowsAction: 'keep'
```

}

and also in update method I am doing this

```
.subscribe((success: any) => {
      this.gridApi?.setRowData(this.updatedData);
      this.updatedData = success;
    }, retry(2));
```